# how to load keras models which are being called within a function outside the URL's endpoint?

Tags: python, nginx, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

i have the following script which currently is working fine (although quite slow 33s/qry). **My main problem right now is that i am calling the `loadweights()` function under the `\predict` endpoint and so everytime i start a query it starts initializing the the keras models and the weights which makes it really slow**. i somehow want to call the function outside the endpoints scope or store the models and weights somewhere. How can i do that? i tried to call the function outside the endpoint just beneath the `loadweights()` definition but it gives me 504 gateway error related to nginx. i am working with flask,nginx,uwsgi on google cloud server.

```
import dlib
import requests
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort, make_response
import tensorflow as tf


app = Flask(__name__)

auth_token = 'WyIxYSDFg467YT'

top_model_weights_ethnicity = '/ethnicity.071217.23-0.28.hdf5'
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
confidence_ethnicity = '0.59'

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
g1 = tf.Graph()

class_to_label_ethnicity = {"0": "arabs", "1": "asia", "2": "black", "3": "hispanics-latinos",
                            "4": "southasia", "5": "white"}


with g1.as_default():
    model_ethnicity = Sequential()
    model_ethnicity.add(Flatten(input_shape=(3, 3, 1536)))
    model_ethnicity.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model_ethnicity.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model_ethnicity.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))


def get_face(path):
    with g1.as_default():
        img = io.imread(path)
        dets = detector(img, 1)
        output = None
        for i, d in enumerate(dets):
            img = img[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right()]
            img = resize(img, (img_width, img_height))
            output = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            break
        return output


def get_pretrained_model():
    with g1.as_default():
        global pretrained_model
        pretrained_model = applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                                                          input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
        return pretrained_model


def get_features(image, pretrained_model):
    with g1.as_default():
        features = pretrained_model.predict(image)
        return features


def loadweights():
     with g1.as_default():
         model_ethnicity.load_weights(top_model_weights_ethnicity)
         pretrained_model = get_pretrained_model()
         return model_ethnicity







@app.route("/predict", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict_ethnicity():
    with g1.as_default():
        loadweights()
        confidence = request.args.get('confidence', confidence_ethnicity)
        path_to_img = request.args.get('url')
        if get_face(path_to_img) is None:
            abort(make_response(jsonify(message="No face found."), 454))
        else:
            features = get_features(get_face(path_to_img), pretrained_model)
            prediction = model_ethnicity.predict_proba(features)
            ethnicity = {class_to_label_ethnicity[str(y)]: str(value) for (x, y), value in np.ndenumerate(prediction)}
            suggestion = class_to_label_ethnicity[str(np.argmax(prediction[0]))] \
                if np.max(prediction[0]) > float(confidence) else ""
        return jsonify({'probabilities': ethnicity, 'suggestion': suggestion}), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```